# Contador SQL Server Row Number

Tags: sql, sql-server, query

como faço para realizar um contador no sql server a partir de um determinado número. Exemplo abaixo.

Resultado atual

```
Ticket   Ação
42977     1
42977     2
```

Resultado esperado

```
42977     3
42977     4
42977     5
```

---Abaixo a consulta---

O primeiro union: Todas com a ação 1
O segundo union: Todas com a ação 2
O terceiro union: Aqui que é para começar a contar a partir do numero 3

1º Ação (Descrição do Chamado)

```
select
s.id Ticket,
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), s.insert_time, 103) + ' '  + convert(VARCHAR(8), s.insert_time, 14) [Data/Hora],
'Pública' [Ação é Pública? (Pública/Interna)],
case when u.ref_id = '1' then '454' else u.ref_id end as Gerador,
description Descricao,
'1' [Seq Ação]
from service_req s
left join sysaid_user u on s.request_user = u.user_name -- Solicitante Gerador da 1º Ação (Descrição do Chamado)
where s.id in(42977)
union all
```

2º Ação (Anotações dos Chamados)

```
select
s.id Ticket,
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), s.insert_time, 103) + ' '  + convert(VARCHAR(8), s.insert_time, 14) [Data/Hora],
'Pública' [Ação é Pública? (Pública/Interna)],
case when u.ref_id = '1' then '454' else u.ref_id end as Gerador, --Responsável
'Todas as anotações (sistema antigo): ' +
s.notes + ' ' as Descrição,
'2' [Seq Ação]
from service_req s
left join sysaid_user u on u.user_name = s.responsibility --Responsável
where s.id in(42977)
union all
```

Demais Ações do Chamado (Mensagens) Contar a partir do 3

```
select
m.id Ticket,
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), m.msg_time, 103) + ' '  + convert(VARCHAR(8), m.msg_time, 14) [Data/Hora],
'Pública' [Ação é Pública? (Pública/Interna)],
case when u.ref_id = '1' then '454' else u.ref_id end as Gerador,
m.msg_body Descricao,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY m.id ORDER BY m.id asc) AS 'Acao'
from service_req_msg m
left join sysaid_user u on m.from_user = u.user_name -- Gerador das Ações
where m.method not in('auto') and m.id in(42977)
order by id asc
```

Comment: Existe uma ordem para fazer isso? como é inserido? tem algum lógica que você não passou para gente entender?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic, Opa amigo. Editei a pergunta. Obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É preciso ficar atento que não faz sentido utilizar a mesma coluna na cláusula PARTITION BY e na ORDER BY. O que se faz é utilizar um conjunto de colunas para definir o grupo (particionamento) e outro conjunto de colunas para definir a ordenação dentro do grupo. É claro que "conjunto de colunas" pode ser uma única coluna ou mais de uma coluna.

Quando se utiliza o mesmo conjunto de colunas nas duas cláusulas, o resultado ordenado não é determinístico; isto é, a cada execução o resultado de linhas pode vir em ordem diferente.

> *como faço para realizar um contador no sql server a partir de um determinado número.*

Utilize uma expressão do tipo:

```
 ...
 2 + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY m.id ORDER BY ____ asc),
 ...
```

Comment: muito obg. Funcionou direitinho